# Close SwiftUI application when last window is closed

Tags: swiftui, appdelegate

Is it possible to close a macOS SwiftUI application when the last window is closed by the user, similar to the `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` AppDelegate function.

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(NSApplication) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 38):

I found the answer here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app

Create a class for the AppDelegate

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Add a property wrapper to your SwiftUI App class

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SwiftUIApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 300, idealHeight: 300, maxHeight: .infinity)
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for an application that can run both on iOS / iPadOS and macOS

Comment: @SébastienStormacq - I just tested with a Multiplatform swiftUI app and the macOS version seems to work fine using this method

Comment: Thank you for having confirmed. I just tested on a macOS only app and I confirm it works.  On my catalyst app (iOS, macOS, iPadOS), I added this entry in Info.plist to make it work (no delegate necessary) " <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
 <dict>
     <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
     <false/>
 </dict>"

Comment: This thread https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710376 has an answer for macOS 13 and later that does not involve AppKit nor Delegates

Comment: @SébastienStormacq - that answer seems to also use a Delegate

Comment: Correct. But no delegate are necessary. I use the “enable multiple windows” in info plist. 

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75081785/663360