# How to solve this in Xcode16.2, Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")

Tags: swift

2022-12-17 11:55:39.440659+0530 StocksApp[83268:1200077] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")

Comment: Try this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/721912?page=2

Comment: I think you are asking for Xcode 14+.
please check on this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74805019/info-plist-contained-no-uiscene-configuration-dictionary-looking-for-configurat

Answer (score 7):

Working on XCode 14.2, I am just starting out on SwiftUI and came across same problem as this. I was trying to solve using the answer above but realised my project does not have an info.plist and went about trying to figure out what could be wrong. Turns out all projects [dont always need it now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67896587/13664649)

Here's how I fixed the problem then.

1. Get to the project properties screen (as per details on linked answer)
2. Go to tab Info
3. Look for Key titled "Application Scene Manifest"
4. Click on the + icon alongside and look for an entry titled "Scene Configuration"
5. There was an entry titled "Enable Multiple Windows" underneath. Based on your application requirements ensure that it is marked to the correct state of "yes" or "no".

[image: Screenshot]
Hope it helps.

Comment: This solved the issue on my end, Xcode 14.2, pure SwiftUI iOS / macOS project.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve that problem by adding on info.plist.

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict/>
</dict>
```

Thank you